# Issue with libGL.so

Tags: 12.04

I am new ubuntu, I have just installed ubuntu 12.04 on hp probook 4530 for my android development, I have installed oracle jdk 6, android sdk and ndk but whenever I start android emulator I got this error

Failed to load libGL.so
error libGL.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I have found a similar post on stackoverflow 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11332817/failed-to-load-libgl-so-in-android

but it does not seems helpful to me, can someone help me to figure out this problem considering I am new to ubuntu

Regards
Ahsan

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/a/12621223/2208271

Answer (score 2):

Does the file `/usr/lib/libGL.so.1` exist on your computer?
You can find it by the command `locate libGL`.

I obtained:

```
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGLU.so.1
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGLU.so.1.3.1
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1.2.0
```